# How to fetch source code or remote server?

Tags: php, html

I want source code of remote website. So I used:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$f = file_get_contents("http://163.53.77.55");
echo htmlspecialchars( $f );
```

I got source code by this... but now I want source code of:

```
$f = file_get_contents("http://163.53.77.55/offers/");
```

and I got this error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://163.53.77.55/offers): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error in

It means I can see source code of stackoverflow.com but can't see stackoverflow.com/questions/!

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. Your request has generated a problem on the remote server. You'll need to look at the server error logs to identify the cause. It's not your server? Contact the server operators then. You can't do that because...?

Comment: i can't do with any website like (www.example.com/abc) not only this.. i mean it is working in www.example.com but in case of example.com/abc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use curl.  But first turn off JavaScript and see if the information you need is there.  For instance the offers page gets it images via JavaScript. 
The designer of this page attempts to discourage you.
When you use curl use an old smartphone User Agent.

**This worked:**

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.flipkart.com";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";

$ch = curl_init('http://www.flipkart.com/offers/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)){
    $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $head = substr($data,0,$skip);
  $data = substr($data,$skip);
 }
echo $data;
```

Comment: Yh It's Working Thanks Now i Have 1 More lil Question ..i Added
$src= htmlspecialchars( $data );
echo $src
to Print Source Code Of that Page ... Now i Want To Print Only n Only Content (inside) starting of this <div class="cf"> to closing of this div...

Comment: echo "<div class="cf">$data</div>

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'cf' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: escape the double quotes.  echo "<div class=\"cf\">$data</div>"

Comment: bro this will print Complite source code i only need code inside this <div class="cf">.....xyz....</div>  tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69004/discussion-between-a-b-and-misunderstood).